# The complexification of a compact connected Lie group, is it semi-simple?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have read that the complexification of a compact Lie group is a reductive Lie group.

**Question:** Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and let $G _\mathbb{C}$ be a complexification of $G$. Is $G _\mathbb{C}$ a semi-simple Lie group  ?

Comment: See for $\Bbb T^n$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group#Classification).

Comment: You should add "without nontrivial normal abelian subgroups" to your list of assumptions about $G$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, If $G$ doesn't contain a nontrivial normal abelian subgroup, then does this imply that $G_\mathbb{C}$ is semi-simple ? Could you please elaborate  further ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Think about the complexification of the Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Nonzero abelian groups are not semisimple.